# How to disable an anchor (link) tag (convert to span)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a bunch of anchor tags (`<a>`) that I need to convert to `<span>` tags.  I don't need to do this to disable clicking (I know about `preventDefault()` and returning `false` from the click event handler).  I just need to do this to enable drag and drop sorting (which IE forbids on an anchor tag but permits on a span).

I have a working solution that is fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/5HGbx/

I'm just wondering if any of you wizards have a slicker way of achieving the same end result.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you could use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) from jQuery API

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $("#someDiv a").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/ufYCt/1/

Comment: I need to keep the attributes of the <a> tag though, so I can undo this operation later. They don't need to be actual HTML in the DOM, but I can't lose the data entirely.  So I ended up storing them with jQuery's `data()` method and came up with this.  http://jsfiddle.net/5HGbx/1/

Answer (score 5):

Mixing standard DOM methods with jQuery is a bit odd and unnecessary. You could just do something like this instead:

```
function aToSpan() {
    var $link = $('a');
    var $span = $('<span>');
    $link.after($span.html($link.html())).remove();
}
```

This just copies the link's content to a new `<span>` and then replaces the `<a>` with the new `<span>`.

References:

- [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
- [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 2):

from the naveen's answer you will lose the **href** tag

if you want href tag too just modify this as follows...

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $("#someDiv a").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<span href=\""+$(this).attr('href')+"\">" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
    });
});
```

Comment: pal this generates invalid markup. span does not have an href tag

Comment: `data-href` would be a better choice for the attribute name, that would even be valid HTML5.